# Creating a Discord Bot Language Filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord Bot Language Filter using Visual Studio Code. I run the program and there are no errors in the console. However, the Bot does not reply when I type in a curse word. I am using the latest version of Node(16.6.2). Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const config = require("./Data/config.json");

const intents = new Discord.Intents(32767);

const client = new Discord.Client({intents});

client.on("ready", () => console.log("Bot is online!"));

client.on("messageCreate", message => { 

    let usermessage = message.content.split(" ");
    console.log(usermessage);

    const s = "4r5e, 5h1t, 5hit, a55";
    let cw = s.split(', ');

    for(var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) { 
        if(usermessage.includes[cw[i]]) { 
            message.delete()
            message.channel.send(`Sorry ${message.author.username}, please restrict yourself from using curse words!`)
        }
    }

});

client.login(config.token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using square brackets `[]` instead of parenthesis `()`. Try using `usermessage.includes(cw[i])` instead of `usermessage.includes[cw[i]]`.

Comment: Idk if it's another typo though

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to type `msg`? If not, you should be using `message.delete()`, `message.channel.send()`, and `message.author.username`. It's probably just a typo.

Comment: Oh, I was playing around with it earlier and I forgot to switch it back. However, it still does not work.